# How to print time remaining

Tags: php, time

[image]

Here is my table. **dateline** column is in hours.

How can I print time remaining in hours based on *dateline*, created_at and *current time*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strtotime()`:

```
<?php

$created = 1323504315;
$timeleft = 144;
$expires = strtotime("+$timeleft hours", $created);

$compare_text = "created: " . date('m/d/Y H:i A',$created) . ", now: " . date('m/d/Y H:i A') . " > expires:" . date('m/d/Y H:i A',$expires);

if (mktime() > $expires) {
    echo "The time has expired. ($timeleft, $compare_text)";
} else {
    echo "The time has not expired. ($timeleft, $compare_text)";
}

?>
```

http://codepad.org/WcCObV1z

Comment: what i wanna do is, to show timeleft and check the row is expired if more than dateline.

Comment: awesome. i need to modify because it not shown expiry time in hours. but its ok. thanks

Comment: @rails_noob - If you have the appropriate version of PHP, [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) would probably come in handy as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$hours = "144"; //from dataline
$totalHours = date("H") - $hours;

$totalMinutes = date("i");

$totalSeconds = date("s");

$totalMonths = date("m");

$totalDays = date("d");

$totalYears = date("Y");

$timeStamp = mktime($totalHours, $totalMinutes, $totalSeconds, $totalMonths, $totalDays, $totalYears);

$myTime = date("H:i A", $timeStamp);
```